# How can I restore a local branch after deleting it?

Tags: git, branch, restore

I had a branch called `my_branch_1` in my local repository, which I deleted.
`my_branch_1` was only local; I never pushed it to a remote server.
Is it possible to restore this branch, somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can see its SHA1 with [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Then you can re-create it:

```
git checkout -b my_branch_1 SHA1
```

You can also have a look at the script (included in a Git distrib): **[`contrib/git-resurrect.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/git-resurrect.sh)**.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021),"`git resurrect`" script (in `contrib/`) learned that the object names may be longer than 40-hex depending on the hash function in use.

See [commit e37eae0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e37eae0c1e13cb418947383f7c803d9463bfa3d7), [commit d047154](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d047154e7b2ab9c7191b0d72484012085051d521) (07 Oct 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f9c0e74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9c0e741a9f0e303b19bc0c0bad6bcbac63c4ab2), 30 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`contrib/git-resurrect.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e37eae0c1e13cb418947383f7c803d9463bfa3d7): use hash-agnostic OID pattern
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> Since Git now supports hashes other than SHA-1, the hash length isn't guaranteed to be 40 characters. Replace `$_x40` with a hash-agnostic OID pattern.

Comment: Hi all,
I'm sorry, sorry I forgot you:-(
but thanks for the tips and the link

Answer (score 1):

VonC has guided you in the correct direction.

But I could not able to stop myself from sharing this wonderful [GithubGist](https://gist.github.com/jbgo/1944238) of recover git branch.