# What if I delete non merged branch?

Tags: git

My question is simple: I deleted a branch called `work-dev` with `-D` flag before being merged. Have I lost everything? Is there approach to retrieve the data?

Comment: Also related: [How can I restore a local branch after deleting it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27186937/216074)

Comment: You can also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716

Comment: Thank you guys. English is not my native language, so I often compose my questions in non formal way. Therefore the topics suggested by SO when I search, are beyond my interest. Anyway, your comments are more than enough. Thank you again.